# sql server Full text different than like results

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I am working on query which seraches for 4.01 using [`CONTAINSTABLE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/containstable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) as " *4.01* ".
I am expecting it would return all results similar to `LIKE %4.01%`. But the results are less in contains query.

Here are the values missing when using the full text query, but displayed by when using the `LIKE` operator:

```
4.01.02.01.01.01
4.01.02.01.01.01
4.01.02.01.01.02
4.01.02.01.01.02
4.01.02.01.01.03
4.01.02.01.01.03
4.02.04.01.01.01
4.02.04.01.01.01
4.02.04.01.01.02
4.02.04.01.01.02
4.04.01.02.0L.01
4.04.01.02.0L.01
4.04.01.02.0N.01
SUB-4.01.01.01
```

How do I get the complete results using Full Text Search? I tried not using a stoplist and also rebuilt the index, but it did not help.